# Shutdown Derby database using JPA not DriverManager

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby, eclipse-gemini

I have an RCP client application that uses embedded Derby in the same JVM for persistence.  I access it via JPA using RESOURCE_LOCAL and Eclipse Link as a JPA provider.  I leave starting the Derby instance to JPA and persistence.xml.

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, props);
```

Persistence.xml

```
<properties>
    <property name="eclipse.weaving" value="false" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:pathToDb" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
</properties>
```

At one point in the application, I need to stop the underlying Derby database. All of the examples show calling:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"); 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:pathToDb;shutdown=true");
```

This is problematic, especially in an RCP application with multiple class loaders (it uses OSGI under the covers). I have tried using

```
if (factory.isOpen())
        factory.close();
```

but this does not shutdown the Derby instance, only the JPA connection to it.

Is there a way, using JPA, to shutdown the underlying Derby instance?

**Update**

I tried using the OSGI console to stop the persistence related bundles including javax.persistence, JPA and Derby.  Stopping these did not release the file locks that Derby put on log files.

**Update 2**

Revised to clarify that the use is not in an OSGI server application.

Comment: A suggestion was made to your query on the derby-user mailing list: http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/Shutdown-Derby-database-using-JPA-not-DriverManager-tp147171p147172.html

Comment: Suggestion : list all services exported by the Derby bundle, maybe there is one that expose the driver or a wrapper around the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not the classloader but an import issue.

An RCP application has a "target platform" that is dynamically searched by the framework for dependencies.  This does not happen when calling Class.forName().  Once I explicitly added the Derby jar to my bundle's dependencies, the class was found and the database is shutting down properly.

Lesson learned: check the simple stuff before assuming it is hard!